Odoo 13 Monetary field not using Decimal
So why is odoo 13 using float data type instead of decimal for monetary field?
I thought decimal is better for calculating money, is there a way to change this so every monetary fields uses decimal?

you'd rather post this kind of question on the odoo forum
